# get button id, post to external php file and load external file into div with updated contents

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am new to php, javascript, mysqli on a whole and I am also new to this forum.

I am in the process of building a website.
On this site, I have buttons on a page being generated as a result of the php while loop as seen in the code below. Each having their own id as a result of the loop like so:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run_c)){

  $memberid = $row['ID'];
  $convoid = $row['c_id'];

  echo"
 <button class='convoid' onClick='getconvo($convoid);'>Open</button>
 ";
}
```

What I really want to to achieve is:  when I click on any of the buttons, the specific id VALUE is detected from the variable $convoid and then that VALUE is sent to an external php file. The external file, having received the id VALUE, will load into a div as seen in the code below, but this is not happending. This is what I have for this so far:

```
<div class='log'></div>

<script type='text/javascript'>
function getconvo(id){ 
id = id; 
$.ajax({ 
data: 'id=' + id,
url: 'fetch_convo.php', 
method: 'POST', // or GET 
success: function(data) { 
$(".log").load(fetch_convo.php);
}

});

}
</script>
```

I have even placed individual load function here but still nothing

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $('.log').load('fetch_convo.php');
 });

</script>
```

To add to the situation, the external file is a php file. Results are fetched from mysqli query based on the id VALUE that was passed through ajax to the file. I have echoed the results in the php file so that something kind of data can be displayed in the div in which I want the file to load into.

The while loop and the external file is working (I tested by manually inputting the id) but how do i get the id VALUE to be posted to the external file and then have the results of that external file load into a div based on the id  VALUE.

Any help would be greatful. Remember that I am new and that I am trying...

Comment: When you do the POST request, does any errors showing up in console? Does the request succeed reaching server side?

Comment: I think you just forgot to put double quotes in your `.load` call in you `getconvo` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do the POST request, does any errors showing up in console? Does the request succeed reaching server side? Seems like you did two request which what you really wanted is only once. When you do `.load()` inside success callback, it never post the data id. Anyway you can try below code.

First of all, it's better to put ID into data attribute like so and noticed that we have a class name `convoid`(we need this) :

```
echo" <button class='convoid' data-id='$convoid'>Open</button>";
```

Then we register click handler to class name `convoid` like following :

```
// document ready
$( function () {
   // register click handler
   // this will attach to all elements with `convoid` class's name
   $(document).on('click', '.convoid', function () {

      var convoid = $( this ).data('id'); // get the ID from data-attribute

      // do post request using .load()
      // noticed that, we send together data during request
      $('.log').load('fetch_convo.php', {id : convoid}, function () {
           // do something when success
      });
   });
});
```

Comment: HI, actually this is working, but now, when i click on the button, it only gets the first id VALUE from the while loop in php (that is, the first value that is assigned to the variable $convoid from the php while loop). I have echoed the id VALUES in the external php file to ensure that this is happening. In the mysqli database, it only has two records now and it only detects the first id VALUE of the first record when any of the buttons is clicked. Why?

Answer (score 0):

Can you change your `echo` statement as follows:

```
echo "<button class='convoid' onClick='getconvo(\"{$convoid}\");'>Open</button>";
```

Using your code, the HTML code generated for the buttons as follows:

```
<button class="convoid" onclick="getconvo(c_id2);">Open</button>
```

The above starts looking for the variable `c_id2`, which does not exist. You would rather want this:

```
<button class="convoid" onclick="getconvo("c_id2");">Open</button>
```

Start using the Javascript Console in the browsers to note errors and fix them.

**Update: Snippet to demonstrate what I am trying to describe above.**

```
<script>
    some_convo_id = "This is coming from the some_convo_id variable";
    function getconvo(convoid) {
        alert(convoid);
    }
</script>

<?php
$convoid = "some_convo_id";

echo "Below, when you click on 'Open', it passes 'some_convo_id' as a string to the function 'getconvo()'";
echo "<br>";
echo htmlspecialchars("<button class='convoid' onClick='getconvo(\"{$convoid}\");'>Open</button>");
echo "<br>";
echo "<button class='convoid' onClick='getconvo(\"{$convoid}\");'>Open</button>";

echo "<br><br>";

echo "Below, when you click on 'Open', it passes value of the variable some_convo_id as a string to the function 'getconvo()'";
echo htmlspecialchars("<button class='convoid' onClick='getconvo($convoid);'>Open</button>");
echo "<br>";
echo "<button class='convoid' onClick='getconvo($convoid);'>Open</button>";

?>
```

Comment: i do not know where you got c_id2 from. Did you see that in my code? Where?

Comment: No I do not see that in the code. Nowhere. I do not know what values you are fetching from your database, which is later being assigned to `$convoid`, and which is then being used in generated HTML. As an example, I mentioned how your HTML will be generated based on arbitrary value of `$convoid`. The main point of that is to convey that it will start to look for the variable with the name of the value of $convoid, instead of treating it as a string and passing it to the `getconvo()` function. And well, Javascript will say the same, I do not see the variable c_id2 anywhere.

Comment: okay. but i was not getting that error like you stated above from javascript. The value of $convoid was recognized because i alerted it to ensure.

Comment: @maraj: I have create a PHP fiddle for you. Check it out, and I hope it will help clear what I'm trying to explain. Even though your problem has been solved, the link will help you to learn more about PHP and JS. Updating the answer with the code in case the fiddle link goes down. http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/sapm-m9ri

Comment: Hey, thanks for the code link. I keep the idea of this fiddle in case i need it in the future.